# Is the Cache-Control metadata header supposed to be respected in a Google Cloud Storage bucket with a bucket-level IAM policy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to see if I can have a Google Cloud Storage bucket, using a [Bucket Policy Only](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-bucket-policy-only) for simplified permissions (in this case, everything is publicly readable), while also serving files with a `Cache-Control` response header for good performance.

I actually already have this working, but I'm asking this question, because I want to validate whether this should actually be working, or if it's some kind of fluke that might stop working.

The reason I'm wary is that the [Object metadata docs on using `Cache-Control`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#cache-control) states that

> `Cache-Control` only applies when accessing objects that [...] Are not stored in a bucket that has Bucket Policy Only enabled

Likewise, the [Bucket Policy Only docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-policy-only#enabled) state that

> Once enabled, the following ACL functionality ceases: [...] Public caching is not supported.

This contradicts a few tests I did. I have buckets that are publicly readable, and by default, files were served with `cache-control: private, max-age=0`, but when I set a `Cache-Control` value in the metadata manually, that was respected.

Here's an example, which demonstrates that the `Cache-Control` headers I've set are in fact respected:

```
# Show that Bucket Policy Only is enabled
$ gsutil bucketpolicyonly get gs://bucketname
Bucket Policy Only setting for gs://bucketname:
  Enabled: True
  LockedTime: 2019-11-21 02:30:26.811000+00:00

# Create and upload a dummy file
$ touch test-file
$ gsutil cp test-file gs://bucketname/test-file
Copying file://test-file [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
/ [1 files][    0.0 B/    0.0 B]
Operation completed over 1 objects.

# Show default cache-control headers on the public file
$ curl -vso /dev/null 2>&1 https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname/test-file | grep cache-control
< cache-control: private, max-age=0

# Set cache-control headers and show that they are in fact returned
$ gsutil setmeta -h "cache-control: public, max-age=7200" gs://bucketname/test-file
Setting metadata on gs://bucketname/test-file...
/ [1 objects]
Operation completed over 1 objects.
$ curl -vso /dev/null 2>&1 https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname/test-file | grep cache-control
< cache-control: public, max-age=7200
```

**Are the docs wrong, in which case I can just expect this to work out, or is this actually a bug, that I shouldn't depend on in the long run?**

Comment: Show the policy applied to the bucket, the HTTP headers returned from an HTTP request and object metadata for an example bucket object. Edit your question with this information.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've updated the question with a demo

Comment: I will try to reproduce this.

Comment: I have updated my answer with new information from Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a documentation error. I recommend opening a Cloud Storage Issue here:
https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Setting cache-control for an entire bucket makes no sense. `cache-control` for objects should be set at the individual object level and not for an entire bucket. The default value is `private, max-age=0` which would prevent caching if you could not change it. Plus you cannot set `cache-control` on a bucket, so if `bucketonlypolicy` is for an entire bucket, there is no way to set it.

[EDIT 9/3/19] Google has updated the documentation. The following pages have been updated as a result of this question.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-policy-only#restrictions

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#cache-control

> The value of `Cache-Control` is set to `private` by default for publicly
>   accessible objects in Bucket Policy Only-enabled buckets, unless you
>   explicitly set the value to `public`.

[END Update]